# What other expressions and sayings do you have as an alternative to ‘Rip Van Winkle meets Facebook.’?

Tags: catch-phrases

In today’s (Feb.10) [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/11/opinion/11friedman.html) titled *Out of Touch, Out of Time* written by Thomas L. Friedman, I found a really cool phrase, *this is Rip Van Winkle meets Facebook*, which I understand describes Hosni Mubarak's preposterous decision. In Japanese, when we encounter such an anachronism, we say *it’s like meeting an old ghost on the road*, *ghost has come back*, or *return to Genji/Heike-era*.

Note:Genji and Heike were two martial clans rivaling for the hegemony of Japan through 11–12 century.

Because Friedman uses a recent word, Facebook, this witty remark seems to be his own coinage to me. I think you have many other well-worn English epigrams corresponding to *Rip Van Winkle meets Facebook*. Can you give me some of old versions?

> Watching President Hosni Mubarak addressing his nation Thursday night, explaining why he would not be drummed out of office by foreigners, I felt embarrassed for him and worried for Egypt. This man is staggeringly out of touch with what is happening inside his country. This is Rip Van Winkle meets Facebook.

Comment: Why were "Rip"s from this question (and as in original article) substituted by capitalized "RIP"s, as I see, by non-author edition of question?  I am really confused - what is it supposed to mean? And why was this question made "community wiki"?

Comment: @vgv8: I've reverted the incorrect edit. I don't know why it was made CW, and that seems erroneous as well.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: A question is automatically changed to CW, when it is edited by 5 different users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*old meets new*

*stone-age meets space-age*

*Fred Flintstone meets George Jetson*